# Tcl namespace renaming to avoid conflicts

Tags: namespaces, tcl, rename, itcl

I want to rename or delete namespace in tcl, can anyone tell me how to do it?

```
rename gk ""
```

Here gk is the namespace

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any way to rename an existing namespace. To delete a namespace:

```
namespace delete namespace_name
```

All the child namespaces, proc, vars within the namespace will be deleted as the result of this call.

Comment: Namespaces cannot be renamed. There's no operation to do so, and the implementation strongly assumes that it is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Use this proc to rename any given namespace:

```
proc renameNameSpace {oldNameSpace newNameSpace} {
    foreach proc [info procs ::${oldNameSpace}::*] {
        rename $proc ::${newNameSpace}::[lindex [split $proc ::] end]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this approach offers a solution. Where ns1 is the source namespace, and ns2 the destination.

```
proc xxxx {ns1 ns2}  {
    namespace eval ::${ns2} {}
    set map [list $ns1 $ns2]
    
    foreach type {commands vars procs } {
        foreach item [info $type ${ns1}::*] {
            set err ""
            catch { rename $item [string map $map $item] } err
            if { $err != "" } { puts $err }
        }
    }
namespace delete $ns1
}
```